# SQL Server 2005 Cluster Service pack 4 upgrade failure at remote user account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005

I built SQL Server 2005 ENT Cluster on Windows Server 2008 R2. I need to upgrade it to SQL Server 2005 SP4. However, I get this error at the Remote User Account screen

> Enter the remote user account name and password below.
>   User name, Password and domain fields.
>   Your account information could not be verified.
>   Press Ok to return to Authentication mode screen to determine the reason for failure.
>   For setup to verify your credentials the services must be startable, connectable, and you must be a SQL Server Administrator

I am using  an domain account that has access and local admin rights to both servers. The SQL Server and agent run as this domain account and sysadmin .

I got connected using the active node name and also using the virtual name and I get the same error. I also made sure no one is connected to the passive node.

This is my exact error message on the link. But none helped.
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sqlserver/sqlsetupandupgrade.aspx?ID=89159030-1f3d-4f13-a693-8122b6bb6aae

The link below from discusses "To work around this problem, use the NetBIOS name of the domain instead of the FQDN" but I do not know where I would be using . 
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=932870

Thanks

Comment: Oh, the wonders of the 2005 service pack installer. In the installer only use the netbiosname for the cluster nodes - COMP1, COMP2 but not comp1.domain.com. Also enter the usename as DOMAIN\USER but not user@domain and run the installer on the active node.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem with installing sql server 2005 service pack 3 on windows 2008 R2 cluster. On node1, i brought the sql server group online and pause the Node2 in cluster Manager and then ran the set up on node1. Once setup completed, i resume the node2 and failed over the SQL Server group on node2. Now on Node2, i pause Node1 in cluster manager and run the setup on node2. Once setup was completed, i resume Node1 and rebooted both nodes. I verified the version by failing over the sql server on both nodes.